# Automatic lazy-loading in datatable from primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, lazy-loading

Is there some easy way or maybe a ready component to use lazy-loading in `dataTable` by Primefaces but without pagination (also not the standard one) ?

I need following feature: when page is loaded `dataTable` contains only first 10 out of 100 rows (fast response time).
The rest of rows is automatically loaded into the `dataTable` but user can already work with first portion of data.

Thanks for any advice. In worst case I will have to implement similar behavior by myself, but maybe someone already have some experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature you're looking for comes very close with "live scrolling". It does load in the background, but only when the bottom is reached in scrolling. See the ["DataTable - Scrolling"](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableScrolling.jsf) showcase page.

Here's an extract of relevance from the showcase example, showing the attributes you need:

```
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{tableBean.carsLarge}" scrollRows="20"  
    scrollable="true" liveScroll="true" scrollHeight="150" id="dataTable4">
```

However, to achieve exactly your functional reqirement, you'd probably need to homebrew or post a new feature request to PrimeFaces guys.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's almost exactly what I'm looking for. Unfortunately I have overlooked this showcase.